# format as GMT/UTC time when default timezone is something else

Tags: java, date, timezone

I have a program which needs to run under my local timezone for other reasons, but for one procedure i need to output dates using a SimpleDateFormat in GMT.

what is the tidiest way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the [standard API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/time/package-summary.html):

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
String result = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.LONG)
                                 .withZone(ZoneId.of("GMT"))
                                 .format(now);
System.out.println(result);
```

The new [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) instances are immutable and can be used as static variables.

Using the old standard API:

```
TimeZone gmt = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG);
formatter.setTimeZone(gmt);
System.out.println(formatter.format(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 8):

Given that `SimpleDateFormat` isn't thread-safe, I'd say that the tidiest way is to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net) instead. Then you can create a single formatter (calling `withZone(DateTimeZones.UTC)` to specify that you want UTC) and you're away:

```
private static DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(...)
    .withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);

...

String result = formatter.print(instant);
```

This has the other benefit that you can use Joda Time elsewhere in your code, which is *always* a good thing :)

Comment: @John Skeet In how far is Thread-Safety relevant in this case? I have the time in ms and I need to convert it to a UTC String with a specific format. Is McDowells answer not correct?

Comment: @Zainodis: It's fine if you're happy to create a new `DateFormat` each time. Personally I prefer the Joda Time approach though - heck, partly because Joda Time is simply a much nicer API.

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you very much for the reply. I totally agree, that the Java date/time/calendar API is a huge pain. However since in my case I am working on android apps, I'd rather keep their size down by only using the libraries I can't do without. JodaTime would be a lot better than having to deal with that Java time-stuff, but it's not unbearable enough to justify adding another library :).